# SQL : Adding foreign key on existing composite key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have two tables with data in them. We needed some restructuring so now I need to add  Foreign Key constraint on one table which refers to composite key from other table.
These are the table definitions
Table ABC

```
CREATE TABLE ABC(
ID [int] NOT NULL,
ChangeNo [int] NOT NULL,
    ...
UserID [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_ABC PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
ID,ChangeNo)
)
```

Table PQR

```
CREATE TABLE PQR(
ID [int] NOT NULL,
UserID [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
...
CONSTRAINT PK_PQR PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
ID,UserID)
)
```

To add Foreign Key I am using following query

```
ALTER TABLE ABC
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ABC_PQR FOREIGN KEY (UserID,ID)
 REFERENCES PQR(UserID,ID)
```

But by doing this I am getting following error.

```
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_ABC_PQR". The conflict occured in database "MyDatabase", table PQR.
```

I was searching on net and I got to know that before adding foreign key, I should check that there are no data difference between respective columns of both tables. I cross verified it using following command.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID,UserID
FROM ABC
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM PQR)
AND UserID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM PQR)
```

And this query returned no results. It means that all data in respective columns of ABC is in those respective columns of PQR. But still I am getting the same error as i stated above, am I missing something here? Could you guys please guide me in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to you to check data using following query:

```
SELECT count([ABC].[id])
FROM [ABC]
   LEFT JOIN [PQR] ON ([ABC].[UserID] = [PQR].[UserID] AND [ABC].[id] = [PQR].[id])
WHERE [PQR].[id] is null
```

---

> And this query returned no results. It means that all data in
>   respective columns of ABC is in those respective columns of PQR.

No, it only means that for each pair (`userid`, `id`) in `ABC` table there is a respective value of both `id` and `userid` in `PQR` talbe, but not a respective pair of values (i.e. they may not be in a single row)

For instance, you may have pairs: `(1,2)` + `(2,1)` in `ABC`, and `(1,1)` + `(2,2)` in `PQR` and your query will return `0` rows. But the foreign key constraint will fail.

Comment: Thanks. This actually returned some 100+ pairs. It means that I have to add those distinct pairs to table PQR first and then apply Foreign Key constraint. Is that right?

Comment: Thanks Artur! That worked like a charm! I added those missing pairs found by way you suggested and then added foreign key constraint and it worked. :-)